# Snakify returns 'NameError: <ReferenceError: int is not defined>'

Tags: python

For some reason, Snakify (a python learning tool online) returns 'NameError: ' after running the below code, and the program crashes.

```
from math import sqrt
from decimal import Decimal

n = int(input())
def F(n):
    return Decimal((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5))
print(F(n))
```

The code is to print the nth Fibonacci number. I don't understand how 'int' is 'not defined'

Comment: It works almost for me on repl.it ... the error I face is in your function where you do a Decimal / float (unsupported operand types TypeError). However, the error you mention above doesn't occur when I run it.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that.